# nginx multiple virtual hosts - error - too much files?

Tags: http, ssl, nginx, https

We use nginx for Hosting multiple hosts.
We have haves mixes, some sites are only available at http:// and other sites are able with http**s**://

We create a new config-file for every virtual hosts (domain) if there is a new customer with a new Homepage.
All works correctly.

Today we create 2 new config-files on the nginx, copy the file to sites-enabled and make a nginx reload.

Now, no sites works again.

In the Browser we get the error that the Site is not available.

In the nginx error.log we get the message 
***2948... no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 178...., server 0.0.0.0:443**

The Virtual-Host config File we create look like:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.de;
   return 301 http://www.$http_host$request_uri;
}
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name *.example.de;
   location / {
      access_log off;
      proxy_pass http://example.test.de;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwareded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_sestheader Connection "upgrade";
   }
}
```

We get the error only if we create a new virtual-host file in the sites-enabled. if we copy the code into a exisiting virtual host file it works correctly and all other sites works again.

Any Ideas why it doesn't work if we create a new file? 
We deleted the new file, create it again but always get the same effect with the error Message in the error-log file.

I don't know if its important but we have 196 Files in the sites-enabled directory. If we create a new one the error come again, if we delete the file and write the code into a existing file it works correctly?!

We don't think that is a ssl error, we think that the count of files are the problem?!

We want to create always a new virtual-host config-file for each customer and don't edit add the config to a existing file.

Comment: that's a very strange issue. Check for any syntax errors in other files (like the one preceding in alphabetic order maybe, like one extra `{` somewhere and one extra `}` in another place... especially because this seems to work if you copy the instructions in another place (test the syntax error by also altering the filename to check if the include order has an impact).

Comment: @regilero: thx for your answer.
FYI: Yesterday, we created a additionally directory for the virtual-host files and insert there the new files. We included the new directory in the config-file of the nginx.conf, and now it works!
We don't know why, we think that the count of the files in the "normal" sites-enabled directory are the problem or so?!
With this solution, it works correctly without any errors.
maybe i look for some syntax errors in the virtual-host files and let you know here if i found something.
but it take a while, because there are 196 files i have to check to.